# What is the API Name of Remainder Field in Task?

Tags: trigger, datetime, tasks

[image]

I am creating a task via trigger which is working fine, but how to update  this remainder field value  via trigger.

even in page layout also it is not visible and in "Task fields " also it is not there

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name is: ReminderDateTime

Documentation link here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_task.htm

Answer (score 2):

From the [ObjectReference](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/object_reference/object_reference.pdf), there are two fields that are needed. The first is a boolean, `IsReminderSet`. If that field is set to true, then the field `ReminderDateTime` (Date-Time) can be updated.

**Description:**
Represents the time when the reminder is scheduled to fire, if IsReminderSet is set to
true. If IsReminderSet is set to false, then the user may have deselected the
reminder checkbox in the Salesforce user interface, or the reminder has already fired at the
time indicated by the value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

As per doc : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_task.htm

```
trigger taskreminder on Task (before update, before insert) {

    for(task t : trigger.new){
        if(t.ReminderDateTime!= null){
            t.IsReminderSet = true;
            t.ReminderDateTime = system.now();
        }
    }
}
```